# In THREE.js animate between two points on a sphere

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

Looking to figure out how to rotate a sphere to move one point on the sphere to where another point on the sphere is, similar to the image attached below.

[image: Diagram of the intended motion]
*A diagram of the intended motion*

I have found posts explaining the problem in unity, which they normally refer to a function Quaternion.FromToRotation, but not seeing an equivalent in Three.js.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of a built-in method such as *Quaternion.FromToRotation* for *three.js*, but you can implement the rotation from *B* to *A* with just a few lines.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

const vector_B = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1).normalize();
const vector_A = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1).normalize();

const n = vector_B.clone().cross(vector_A).normalize();
const theta = vector_B.angleTo(vector_A);
const q = new THREE.Quaternion(n.x * Math.sin(theta / 2), n.y * Math.sin(theta / 2), n.z * Math.sin(theta / 2), Math.cos(theta / 2));

sphere.applyQuaternion(q);
```

Here I took a guess as to where vectors **B** and **A** were pointing. I took advantage of the mathematical fact that the quaternion **q** that rotates from **B** to **A** can be derived from the normalized cross-product of **B** and **A** (call this **n**) and the angle between **B** and **A** (call this *theta*).

```
const q = new THREE.Quaternion(n.x * Math.sin(theta / 2), n.y * Math.sin(theta / 2), n.z * Math.sin(theta / 2), Math.cos(theta / 2));
```